# How to build custom territories and fill colors by group of zip codes in mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I have custom sales territories that is build on group of zip codes.
How can I show this territories with different colors?

Comment: How is your data currently organised? Do you have geometry for the zip codes?

Comment: I have zip codes grouped by territories.

Answer (score 1):

If the data for your custom sales territories is in a GeoJSON format, you can follow [this example](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-polygon/) from the Mapbox GL JS documentation, which shows how to add a GeoJSON polygon to the map with a custom color. As shown in the linked example, you could add a source and layer for each of your sales territories, and then specify a color for each territory via the `paint` property of the layer object being added. So, for each of your territories, you would use the following code:

```
map.addSource('territory_name', {
    'type': 'geojson',
    'data': {
        'type': 'Feature',
        'geometry': {
            'type': 'Polygon',
            'coordinates': [ list_of_coordinates_defining_territory_boundaries ]
        }
    }
});

map.addLayer({
    'id': 'territory_name',
    'type': 'fill',
    'source': 'territory_name',
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
        'fill-color': 'hex code of color to be used for this territory',
        'fill-opacity': 0.8
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you could upload your data as a [tileset](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/tilesets/) in [Mapbox Studio](https://studio.mapbox.com) and add said tileset as a layer to a custom map style, as described in [this tutorial](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/add-points-pt-2/). The exact steps for this option are a bit more dependent on your underlying data format, but the [Mapbox Studio Manual](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/overview/) is an excellent resource for guidance on using Studio to create highly customized maps based on your own data.